# How to send a DM (Direct Message) to someone on Discord via JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want the bot to send a direct message to someone, but I don't know how to do so.

```java
event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hello World").queue();
```

I wonder if I can change the channel to a DM or send a DM in any other way, I want it sent directly to the user or that only him can see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never have to guess at how to use a library - that's what documentation is for. Any library worth its salt has documentation listing every single class, method, and property you need to worry about.

A quick google search for "discord-jda docs" takes us to the javadoc: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/index.html

You want to send a message to a user, right? So let's use the search bar and find `User`. First result under Types is `net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.User`. We're now at https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/User.html

If you want to know how to *do something with a user*, we look at the Methods every User has. Two catch my eye right away: `User.hasPrivateChannel()` and `User.openPrivateChannel()`. We'll click the second one since it looks relevant.

Lo and behold, the docs have example usage! I'll quote it below:

> ```
> // Send message without response handling
> public void sendMessage(User user, String content) {
>     user.openPrivateChannel()
>         .flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage(content))
>         .queue();
> }
> ```

This seems pretty straightforward. So the basic usage you're looking for (assuming `event` is a `MessageReceivedEvent`) is this:

```
event.getAuthor().openPrivateChannel().flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage("hello")).queue();
```